# Create multiple users inside of docker image when container starts

Tags: docker

Let me see if I can explain myself better than the tile.

I am creating an image that will have an smtp GW and a imap/pop3d service to allow users to send/receive emails. What I want to do is have my container read a file (usernames i will generate passwords 'randomly' when creating the user) when it starts and create the user accounts for those users.

I will export something like

/data/conf

and there will be a file with a list of users. Now I want to read that file at start and create each user there.

Is this even possible? Are there easier ways to accomplish this? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: How would you do this task without Docker?  (If you installed these services on two separate bare-metal servers, how would you configure them?)

Comment: I think OP wants both services in the same container, so the question should be how would he configure them on a single bare-metal server.